# Is limiting density of discrete points (LDDP) equivalent to negative KL-divergence?

Tags: density-function, entropy, information-theory, density-estimation, divergence

Is limiting density of discrete points (LDDP), which is a corrected version of differential entropy, equivalent to the negative KL-divergence (or relative entropy) between a density function $m(x)$ and a probability distribution $p(x)$?

What are the maths of this equivalence, and the conditions that the density and probability functions have to meet? First of all, i thought densities are probability functions.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I just came across it and thought I'd give it a shot for any future visitors to the post.

---

First, some intuition:

As you mentioned, LDDP is a "corrected" version of Shannon's proposal for a continuous version of entropy. LDDP is more appropriate than Shannon's differential entropy because LDDP is the limit of discrete entropy as we approximate a continuous distribution with increasingly dense discrete distributions.

To formalize the above, consider a set $X_N = {x_i}$, where $|X_N| = N$. If we continue increasing $N$, our points $x_i$ "fill" some space. When $N \rightarrow \infty$, $X_N$ approaches some continuous space.

[LDDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_density_of_discrete_points) is given by:  $$H(X) = -\int p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{m(x)} ~\mathrm dx $$

where $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\{\textrm{number of } x_i \textrm{ in } (a,b)\} = \int_a^bm(x)$$

So $m$ is just the density of the space that $X_N$ approaches.

[KL-Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is: $$D_{KL}(p(x)\Vert q(x)) = \int p(x)\log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} ~\mathrm dx$$

So clearly, $H(X) = -D_{KL}(p(x)\Vert m(x))$.

KL-Divergence (roughly) measures *how different* the two distributions are. So $H(X)$ is measuring how similar $p$ is to $m$. For many familiar spaces, like $[0,1]^d$, we can sample the space continuously and have $m(x) = \textit{U}([0,1]^d)$.

Because uniform distributions maximize entropy, it is natural that the continuous version of entropy would give the KL-divergence between the probability distribution in question and a uniform distribution over the same support.

**References**:
See page 201-202 [here](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/jaynes-brandeis62-info-theory-sm.pdf)

Comment: I am afraid I can not (yet) follow how increasing the number of points allows to expand the Shannon theorem. Could you share a little more insight on how to go from Eq. 59 to Eq. 63 in your linked resource? This does not seem to be very well documented anywhere :/